# FCC lattice as a stack of triangular lattices

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals

According to [Marder, Condensed Matter Physics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470617985), Chapter 2:

> Within the planes normal to the vector [1,1,1], the atoms of an [fcc lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_crystal_system) lie in a two dimensional triangular lattice

However, he does not provide a proof of this claim. How would one go about showing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply construct the (111) face and then it will be self-evident.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The vector (1,1,1) is normal to a plane x+y+z=c.  The nearest lattice point is (+1,-1,0) from this.  There are six of these, and it is easy to show the distance from eg +1,-1,0 to +1,0,-1 or +1,0,-1 to 0,0,0 are equal, and thus it must be a triangular lattice.

The same vector in N dimensions (1,1,1,...), produces a simplex-based lattice, is usually how one studies these.